# CakePHP: Passing $this->params['form'] in a requestAction call?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

How can I pass `$this->params['form']` to the controller action I specify in `requestAction` so that I can use the variable in the same way by calling `$this->params['form']`?

Here is what I'm trying (but isn't working):

```
$this->requestAction('/reports/grid', array('params["form"]' => $this->params['form']));
$this->requestAction('/reports/grid', array('$this->params["form"]' => $this->params['form']));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->requestAction('/reports/grid', array('form' => $this->params['form']));
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the 1.3 documentation, you'll need to specify each parameter you want to send off in the request in the `pass` or `named` parameter key - http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/991/requestAction

```
echo $this->requestAction(array('controller' => 'articles', 'action' => 'featured'), array('named' => array('limit' => 3)));

echo $this->requestAction(array('controller' => 'articles', 'action' => 'view'), array('pass' => array(5)));
```

So, it should be something like

```
$this->requestAction('/reports/grid', array('pass' => array($this->params['form'])));
```

Note - There are very few good reasons you would want to use `requestAction`. Please read up on the performance penalties if you haven't already.

Comment: Close, but not quite. Instead of `pass` I just had to use `form`, and remove the `array()` wrapping the parameter. Thanks for the insight :)

Comment: Could you post the solution that worked for you? It might help someone with the same problem. Thanks!